# How to find and get rid of duplicate values in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of languages as `array=["en-ca", "fr-ca", "es-us", "en-us", "es-mx" ...etc]`. There are lot of languages similar which repeats based on the country code.  I want a filter to group them and create an array which just show the first two characters. For example: I want to find all the english [en-ca,en-us,fr-ca,es-mx,es-us] and just show `[en,fr,es]`. I can extract the first two characters by using `split(-)[0]`. But, how to get rid of the remaining values.

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica I have extracted the array with languages.map(lang => lang.substring(0, 2)) which gives me an array with just first two characters as ["en","es","fr","en","es ..etc]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const array = [ "en-ca", "fr-ca", "es-us", "en-us", "es-mx" /*...etc*/ ]

// Removes the country, leaving en, es, pt, etc
const langArr = array.map(item => item.split('-')[0])

// Removes all the duplicates
const result = Array.from(new Set(langArr))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter() to get a new array with the filtered values:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

You can also use include() to check if the checked object contains  the value you are looking for.

https://developer.mozilla.org/he/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Of course you can  combine them if you wish to.
Recommended flow - filter the array , and then split the values

Answer (score 0):

My own suggestion would be:

```js
// the original Array:
let array = ["en-ca", "fr-ca", "es-us", "en-us", "es-mx"],

  // here we use Array.prototype.reduce() to reduce the
  // Array to something else (without modifying the original
  // Array):
  groups = array.reduce(
    // we pass in the accumulator - the thing that
    // Array.prototype.reduce() will return - and
    // the current Array-element of the Array over
    // which we're iterating:
    (acc, curr) => {
    
      // using a destructuring assignment to set
      // the Array values returned after we split
      // the String - using String.prototype.split()
      // - to the named variables:
      let [key, val] = curr.split('-');
      
      // if there is no Object-property for the current
      // key
      if (!acc[key]) {
        // we assign that Object-property - using square
        // bracket notation - and initialise it to an Array:
        acc[key] = [];
      }
      
      // we then use Array.prototype.push to enter the current
      // value into the Array:
      acc[key].push(val);
      
      // returning the accumulator:
      return acc;
    
    // the {} is the accumulator we're passing into the
    // function:
    }, {});
```

```html
<ul></ul>
```

Demo:

```js
let array = ["en-ca", "fr-ca", "es-us", "en-us", "es-mx"],
  groups = array.reduce(
    (acc, curr) => {
      let [key, val] = curr.split('-');
      if (!acc[key]) {
        acc[key] = [];
      }
      acc[key].push(val);
      return acc;
    }, {});

const logObjectToScreen = (objet) => {
  let D = document,
    ul = D.createElement('ul'),
    li = D.createElement('li'),
    span = D.createElement('span'),
    fragment = D.createDocumentFragment();

  Object.keys(objet).forEach(
    (key) => {
      let clone = li.cloneNode();
      clone.textContent = `${key}: `;
      objet[key].forEach(
        (name) => {
          let temp = span.cloneNode();
          temp.textContent = name;
          clone.append(temp);
        });
      fragment.append(clone);
    });

  ul.append(fragment);

  document.body.append(ul);

}

logObjectToScreen(groups);
```

```css
*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul,
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 0.5em;
}

span::before {
  content: '"';
}

span::after {
  content: '," ';
}

span:last-child::after {
  content: '." ';
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/kwbzh0sn/).

References:

- [Arrow function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
- [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
- [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).
- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).
- [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).